# Clear the SimpleListFilter when searching

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using 'search_fields' and 'list_filter' in my site.
when i do a search URL becomes like

① `/ur/corelog/?q=test`

and search function works well,and when I use list_filter url becomes like

②`/url/corelog/?scoreRange=0+-+0.9`

which is expected. what I am worrying is, if I do a search (url becomes as ① ) and then I use a filter the url becomes like ② above and search text is disappearing as I wanted.

```
/url/corelog/?scoreRange=0+-+0.9
```

If I use filter first (url becomes as ② ) and then I use search, url becomes as follows (Search text and filter both includes).

```
url/corelog/?q=test&scoreRange=0+-+0.9
```

I need ① (`/ur/corelog/?q=test`) instead.
and search is not working either.

How can I clear my filter when performing a search?

follow is my admin class and list_filter

```
Class CoreLogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = CoreLogAdminForm
    search_fields = ('question',)
    list_filter = (RangeFilter,)

    list_display = ('question', '_predicted_result', 'datetime_created')
    fields = ('question', 'predicted_result', 'datetime_created')



class RangeFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

    title = 'Score'
    parameter_name = 'scoreRange'
    template = 'admin/shuchi_logging/input_filter.html'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('Yes', ''),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):

        value = self.value()

        """
        making queryset
        """

        return queryset
```

Comment: you want search first , then filter after search ?

Comment: If I search after filter, I need to clear my filter and then perform only the search.

Comment: in my opinion, maybe in `def queryset:` of `class RangeFilter`. If you have any param of search_fields, you can return queryset directly without any making queryset.

Comment: @Ngoc Pham thanks this was some what working. but query string parameter has still on the url. btw if you add this as a answer ill accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `def queryset:` of `class RangeFilter`. If you have any param of `search_fields`, you can `return queryset` directly without any making queryset.